# Effect of "Version" setting in Bandai Namco's Arcade Game Series: Galaga (Steam)

Tags: galaga

In Bandai Namco's "Arcade Game Series: Galaga", available from Steam, there is a setting "Version" which can be set to "NEW" (default) or "OLD". There is text which says "Enemies become unable to fire under certain conditions" (but doesn't indicate if this applies to "NEW" or "OLD").

Does anyone know if this refers to the bug in the original coin-operated arcade game where killing all but one or two enemies on the far left side and then dodging passively for up to 20 minutes whould lead to no firing by enemies in the rest of the game?

If so, does that happen with Version set to "OLD" or to "NEW"?